# How can I set two Foreign Keys in a class? DJANGO ORM

Tags: python, django, orm, backend, models

I need to make a table 'Friend' with foreignkeys that store instances of the User class- two of them one for the friend and one for the user attribute. (Table is of relationships)

How to do this? OnetoOneField doesn;t work. It gives me an error in the terminal if I try to make both of them keys.
So this is two Many to Many relationships from User to Friend.

If it's impossible, what is a better way to set this up?
Can the User table have a One-to-Many relationship to itself?

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    friend_id= models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
```

Comment: Actually a many-to-many ralation creates a new mapping table with two foreign keys, in the background. So if you don't want to replace the User class you approach look good.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably seen this error while trying to make migrations:

```
appname.Friend.friend_id: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Friend.friend_id' clashes with reverse query name for 'Friend.user_id'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Friend.friend_id' or 'Friend.user_id'
```

It clearly tells, that you should add the `related_name` argument:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    friend_id = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='user_id')
```

Here is [Django docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) about the best practices on customizing and extending the exicting User model.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a new User class inheriting from django's user and in it you would create friends as many to many from User.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models import CharField, ManyToManyField
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class User(AbstractUser):
    name = CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    friends = ManyToManyField('self', related_name='friends')
```

Comment: Rather than posting several distinct answers on the same question, [edit your first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45970593/edit) and add all the info from your other answers there.